# Automatically upgrade a dart package

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I have a package on github and it is been used in two of my projects, but every time I make a change to the package I have to run `flutter pub upgrade` on both projects. Is there a way to make this automatically? Or some way to force me to run the command on every update?

Comment: You can use your package locally in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: The package is imported using a url to my git repository in pubspec.yaml. If I used a local package I would'nt be able to see these changes on my hackintosh or any other computer

Comment: If you import your package locally instead of a git url, each time you make a change in your project, you will just need to run `flutter pub get` (no updgrade commands).